# Figlet error: text does not match

Tags: kali-linux, banner

I have an error with Figlet command: the output text does not match the input.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Also, if you want to play with `figlet`, Kali is the wrong platform. Says not I, says [the official Kali documentation on that](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). Please read it!

Comment: It looks like you're using a variable-width font in your terminal. I'd expect any command that uses spaces for horizontal alignment to produce "wiggly" output.

Answer (score 3):

`figlet` (text to ASCII converter) works fine. It's just that you set your terminal font to **variable width** (instead of **fixed width** aka **monospace**) so the output lines are compressed.

Set your terminal font to any fixed width font like Courier, Liberation Mono, Ubuntu Mono etc. and the problem will be solved.

Besides, using a variable width font will also mess up all output from other commands.